# Does 'code=sm_X' embed only binary (cubin) code, or also PTX code, or both?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I am little bit confused about the 'code=sm_X' option within the '-gencode' statement.

An example: What does the NVCC compiler option

```
-gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13
```

embed in the library ?

Only the machine code (cubin code) for GPUs with CC 1.3, or **also** the PTX code for GPUs with CC 1.3 ?

In the 'Maxwell compatibility guide', it is stated "Only the back-end target versions(s) specified by the 'code=' clause will be retained in the resulting binary".

From that, I would infer that the given compiler option only embeds machine code for GPUs with CC 1.3 and *no* PTX code. This would mean that it would **not** be possible to run this library e.g. on aa Maxwell generation card, as there is no PTX code embeded within the library from which the machine code could be 'just-in-time' (JIT) compiled.

On the other side, on the GTC 2013 presentation 'Introduction to the CUDA Toolkit as an Application Build Tool' by NVIDIA it is stated that the '-gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13' is enough for all GPUs with CC >= 1.3, and that with this compiler option for GPUs with CC > 1.3 the machine code is JIT-ed from the PTX code. So, the information given in the Maxwell compatibility guide and this GTC presentation is conflicting in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nvcc` has many formats by which the code generation options can be specified.  A read of [section 6 of the nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#gpu-compilation) may be instructive.

when using this format:

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 ...
```

*only* the SASS code for a sm_13 (cc 1.3) device will be retained.  There will be no PTX retained in the executable object, and so the code can *only run* on a device capable of running cc1.3 SASS.

Using the above command format, in order to embed a PTX version of the source code into the executable object, it's necessary to use a *virtual architecture specification* for the option provided to `code=...`.  Since this particular format (using `-gencode`) does not allow specification of multiple targets in a single switch, we must pass the `-gencode` switch multiple times to nvcc, one for each target we desire to be embedded in the executable object.

So extending the above example, we could use the following:

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=compute_13 ...
```

This would embed both cc1.3 SASS (by the first `gencode` switch) and cc1.3 PTX (by the second `gencode` switch) in the executable.  Devices capable of running cc1.3 SASS code directly will use that.  Other devices (of compute capability greater than cc 1.3) will do a JIT-compile step by the driver, to convert the cc1.3 PTX code to a SASS code with an architecture suitable for the device in question.

I agree that [the GTC 2013 presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/cuda-toolkit-as-build-tool.pdf) (e.g. slide 37) seems to suggest that

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 ...
```

is sufficient for all devices of compute capability 1.3 or higher.  It is not, and this is easy to demonstrate.  If you compile a code using the above format, and attempt to run it on a cc 2.0 device, it will fail with an "invalid device function" error associated with any kernel or kernels you have in your code.

Again, `nvcc` has a variety of command formats and "shortcuts" for specifying code generation.  Some relatively simple ones, such as:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_13 ...
```

will embed both a PTX and SASS version of the code in the executable object, resulting in the kind of forward-compatibility suggested.

Comment: thx for the clear and concise answer, that resolves all of the question marks in my brain :-)

Comment: gencode only allows one virtual architecture per switch, but you can specify multiple targets like this: nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_13,code=compute_13,sm_13