# CUDA "invalid argument" error when starting kernel

Tags: cuda

I have a problem when kernel launches. I launch a kernel with a grid size of (3000000, 16), and CUDA reports an "invalid argument" runtime error here. I tried different `maxPixelCount` value and found: when `maxPixelCount` is 200000, the error is reported, while when it's 50000, it continues without error.

```
dim3 dimGrid(maxPixelCount, imageCount);
printf("grid: %d * %d * %d", dimGrid.x, dimGrid.y, dimGrid.z);
mcudaGetGrayDataKernel <<< dimGrid, 1 >>> (deviceDestDataPtrs, deviceImageDataPtrs, deviceSizes);

cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("cuda start kernel error\n%s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus);
    goto Error;
}
```

I checked the max grid size to ensure my card's ability, using the following sentence:

```
printf("    - max grid size: %d * %d * %d\n", 
    prop.maxGridSize[0], 
    prop.maxGridSize[1], 
    prop.maxGridSize[2]);
```

I got the following message:

```
- max grid size: 2147483647 * 65535 * 65535
```

I think this means my dim is in the proper range. But why does the error appears?

---

My IDE is Visual Studio 2013

---

This problem has been solved. To reach the max limit of grid size, the `Device`->`Code Generation` option has to be set to the proper version. For my GPU I modified it to `compute_30,sm_30`.

Comment: how are you compiling your code?  If you compile for cc2.0 (default for CUDA 6.5, 7, 7.5) then you will have a lower limit of 65535 imposed.  To get the higher limit of 2147483647  you need to compile for a cc3.0 or higher device.   A switch like `-arch=sm_30` on the compile command line might be all you need.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I modified the project **CUDA C/C++** properties: In **Device**, I modified the `Code Generation` option to `compute_20,sm_30`. In **Host**, I modified the `Additional Compiler Options` option to `-arch=sm_30`. But the problem still remains. And a compiling warning was reported: `1>cl : command line warning D9002: ignored unknown option "-arch=sm_30"`

Comment: `compute_20,sm_30` won't work.  You should choose `compute_30,sm_30`  And you seem to have changed more than just the code generation option (wherever you added `-arch=sm_30`, remove that).  Since you're struggling with this, you could also just take your code and drop it into the `vectorAdd` cuda sample project, and compile it there.  And of course you will need a cc3.0 or higher GPU to run it on.

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you! BTW, what do `compute` and `sm` mean respectly?

Comment: " what do compute and sm mean respectly? "  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232500/does-code-sm-x-embed-only-binary-cubin-code-or-also-ptx-code-or-both/26238964#26238964) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599189/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-multiple-arch-flags-in-nvidias-nvcc-compiler/17599585#17599585) should help with that.

Answer (score 3):

This formulation:

```
dim3 dimGrid(maxPixelCount, imageCount);
```

places `maxPixelCount` in the .x dimension of the variable (`dimGrid`) that will be used to specify the grid dimensions of the kernel launch:

```
mcudaGetGrayDataKernel <<< dimGrid, 1 >>> ...
```

By referring to [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) (or you can use the `deviceQuery` sample code, or query the data yourself programmatically), we can see that devices of compute capability 2.0 only support up to a 65535 limit on the .x dimension of the grid.  In order to achieve the larger dimension (2^31 - 1) available in a compute capability 3.0 (or higher) device, it's necessary to:

1. compile for a compute capability 3.0+ device `<and>`
2. run the code on a compute capability 3.0+ device.

There are various methods to specify how to compile for a compute capability 3.0 device.  Most of the CUDA sample code projects demonstrate this for windows and linux (Makefile) projects.  For more information on how to compile for a given device architecture, and what the various switches mean, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232500/does-code-sm-x-embed-only-binary-cubin-code-or-also-ptx-code-or-both/26238964#26238964) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599189/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-multiple-arch-flags-in-nvidias-nvcc-compiler/17599585#17599585) and the relevant section of [the nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures).